# Is this the best scenario for doing it ?

Tags: alfresco

I'm trying to implement the multi language or bilingual content and i notice the follwoing:

- create a content
- change content language filter from user profile.
- update content with the preferred language

Now, the content is bilingual or muli language this is the alfresco scenario, is there any other scenario for doing this ? is there any other way inline ? is there any other way using Alfresco API ?

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks. 
Mohammed amr

Answer (score 1):

API wise, it depends slightly on what you're trying to do.

One option is to define properties to be Multilingual, and then set multiple values (one value per locale). See [Multilingual Document Support](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Multilingual_Document_Support) on the Alfresco wiki for details of the modelling and use of this.

Alternately, you can have one node per language, and link them together as translations. This is provided by the [Multilingual Content Service](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/ml/MultilingualContentService.html)

If you want to mark something as a translation in the UI, then in Explorer go to the document details of a node. On the right hand side, hit "Make Multilingual", and then specify the language it's in. You can then add translations of it for the additional languages you want for it.